# Windows Firewall blocks SQL Server after installing Update KB4505224

Tags: sql-server

after installing the SQL Server Update KB4505224 this weekend, I’m no longer able to connect to the SQL server from the network. On localhost it still works.

If I disable the windows firewall entirely it works again.
Are there any known issues with this update?

My firewall rules look like this:

- Allow everything for %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MYSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe
- Allow TCP and UDP for 1433 and 1434

The SQL Server uses dynamic ports.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please download and install Cumulative Update 17 from [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4515579/cumulative-update-17-for-sql-server-2017) URL.

After installing CU17, make sure you have configured Windows Firewall as stated on [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation.